# Android MVP with ViewPager presenter life cycle

Tags: android, android-viewpager, mvp

I'm building an mvp application with view pager.
one of my tab's has a recyclerview thats updates from presenter.
when should i register/unregister the presenter?
and what is the best way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presenter should usually be registered in `onResume` and unregistered in `onPause`. The reasoning behind it is that since you might be passing context to the presenter, you want to avoid memory leaks. Also, you want to cache the presenter throughout the lifetime of the `Activity` so that it can be reused and reduce wait time for the user.

Of course this depends on your design and what you are doing. Maybe you need to think about memory limitations. In that case maybe the presenter is tied to an event and then destroyed as soon as user is done with it, e.g. if you have heavy duty video streaming. You might want to register when the user scrolls to the view and then unregister as soon as user scrolls away.

More importantly if the activity is not being shown to the user, then what is there to present? If you have an answer to that question then you should rethink the design and use a `Service` instead, which is more suitable for background operations.

Hope this helps.